# c# how to get tables in the footer of a word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I got some problems with the Microsoft office library in C#. When I try to get the table present in my first page's footer, the programme cannot find it, I can only get the table in text format :

```
object nom_fi = (object)chemin;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = false;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref nom_fi, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
doc.Activate();

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section sec in doc.Sections)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = sec.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table t = range.Tables[0];
}
doc.Close();
```

Thanks for your attention

EDIT : exception :

[image]

It says : "Member of required collection does not exists"

Comment: What do you mean with "the programme cannot find it, I can only get the table in text Format"?

Comment: I have an exception:

Comment: I can get range.Text, and it return footer fields separated by \t\ and others, but range.Tables[0] return exception

Comment: I would start with Debugging `doc.Sections` to see which Footers, Ranges etc. What do you get?

Comment: I can see 3 differents sections : 1st page, last page and others pages together. He count 3 different footers and headers too (1 per section), so wdHeaderFooterPrimary seems to be the right footer choice. Then it throw exception when trying to get the first table of the first footer (that exists btw).

Comment: Have you tried `range.Tables[1];`

Comment: same error as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your section is setup to feature a different first page header/footer, you would need to get that particular first page footer using `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage`:

```
Range range = sec.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range;
```

If you don't know the section/page setup of your document, you can get the range of the footer that appears on the first page as follows:

```
Range range;
if (sec.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Exists)
{
    range = sec.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range;
} 
else 
{
    range = sec.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range; 
}
```

Note that the table index starts at 1 (something already mentioned in the comments), so that you will need to adjust your code to `Table t = range.Tables[1];`

---

Note that you can make your code a lot more readable by importing namespaces with `using` directives at the top of your file, by omitting optional parameters, and by removing the explicit `object` declarations (the latter things were required only in early versions of .NET):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

var wordApp = new Application();
var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(chemin, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
doc.Activate();

foreach (Section sec in doc.Sections)
{
    var range = sec.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range;
    var table = range.Tables[1];
}

doc.Close();
```

Comment: the problem was with the index which start at 1. I know that I should use "using" directives, but I already use System.Data.DataTable and there was some conflicts

Comment: @alexay68: In a comment you said the problem wasn't the index, hence my answer. Regarding the `using` directive: You can always use a named import, e.g. `using Word=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;` and then use the name in the code, e.g. `var wordApp = new Word.Application();`

Comment: The problem was the iteration of Sections btw... I needed to get Sections[1] and not to do a foreach (foreach isn't important because documents have always the same footer structure to get ISO 9001 norm)